# Align text left to equation aligned center

Tags: align, alignment

I am trying to align some text left to an equation which has to be aligned in the center.
For now I have tried this, but now my equation is aligned to the right. How do I solve this?

```
\begin{flalign*}
(EFQ) && A \wedge \neg A \rightarrow B, 
\end{flalign*}
```

Comment: Just add `&&` to the right of the line

Answer (score 2):

If the equation needs to be centered you need to add further `&&` on the right *and* introduce an amount of space equivalent to the text you are writing on the left

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Two \verb+&&+ without horizontal space correction
\begin{flalign*}
(EFQ)&& A \wedge \neg A \rightarrow B, &&
\end{flalign*}
Two \verb+&&+ with \verb+\hphantom+
\begin{flalign*}
(EFQ)&& A \wedge \neg A \rightarrow B, && \hphantom{(EFQ)}
\end{flalign*}
Check with the centred equation
\[
A \wedge \neg A \rightarrow B,
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated, but I believe that `(EFQ)` should rather be in text mode (`\text{(EFQ)}`.